# Load more comments button with PHP and AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am working on a video commenting system, But can't figure out how to get my load more button to work. So far my console is not showing any errors but also nothing is happening. I have checked my PHP script and everything seems to look OK and i get no errors from it.

I am still very unfamiliar with JavaScript, so I think the problem is there somewhere. Can anyone with experience please take a look and explain to me where i am going wrong?

**video comment section:**

```
<div class="comments-display">

        <?php 
            //Get Comments from db 
            $get_comments = db::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM video_comments WHERE video_id = ? LIMIT 0, {$resultsPerPage}", array($vid_id)); 

            if(!$get_comments->results()){ ?>
                <div class="comment-body">
                    <p class="text-center">No Comments....</p>
                </div>
            <?php

            } else {
                foreach ($get_comments->results() as $comment) { ?>
                <div class="comment-header">
                    <?php echo $comment->username . ' | ' . $comment->added; ?> 

                </div>

                <div class="comment-body">
                    <p><?php echo $comment->comment; ?></p>
                </div>

                <?php
                    $x++; 
                }

                if($x == $resultsPerPage) {
                ?>
                <li class="loadbutton"><button class="loadmore" data-page="2">Load More</button></li>

                <?php 
                } else {
                    echo 'no more comments';
                } 
        }
        ?>
</div>
```

**Ajax request:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).on( 'click', '.loadmore', function () {
         $(this).text('Loading...');
         var btn = $(this).parent('li');
          $.ajax({
            url: 'load.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
              page:$(this).data('page'),
            },
            success: function(response){
              if(response){
                btn.hide();
                $(".comments-display").append(response);
              } else {
                alert("error");
              }
            }
          });
    });
</script>
```

**Load.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['page'])){
    $vid_id = 123; 
    $paged = 2;
    $resultsPerPage = 6; 
    $x = 0;
    if($paged>0){
           $page_limit = $resultsPerPage*($paged-1);
           $query = "LIMIT  {$page_limit}, {$resultsPerPage}";
    }else{
            $query = " LIMIT 0 , {$resultsPerPage}";
    }

    $comments = db::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM video_comments WHERE video_id = ? {$query}", array($vid_id)); ?>

    <div id="comments_post" class="comments-display">
                <?php 
                foreach ($comments->results() as $comment) { ?>
                <div class="comment-header">
                <?php echo escape($comment->username) . ' | ' . $comment->added;    
                </div>
                <div class="comment-body">
                    <p><?php echo escape($comment->comment); ?></p>
                </div>
                <?php 
                    $x++;
                }

                if($x == $resultsPerPage) {
                ?>
                <button class="loadmore" data-page="2">Load More</button>
                <?php 
                } else {
                    echo '<h6 class="font-6 text-center pk-blue"> No more Comments! </h6>';

                }?>

    </div>
    <?php 

}
```

Comment: does the button text change to "loading..."?

Comment: no nothing is happening

Comment: Is your console returning *anything*? Is your query firing in `load.php`? Have you checked that? Have you checked the `$.ajax()` response in your console? `escape($comment->username)` where is `escape()` defined? Have you verified that `if(isset($_POST['page'])){` is being met? Should be, but check anyway (add an `else{}` so it returns something). `db::getInstance()` where is that being defined? Have you included your connection file?

Comment: are you including your script tags below where you add jQuery? you are adding jQuery, right?

Comment: @LouisShiggyLombardi If the button isn't changing then the AJAX won't be called either, so the issue lies somewhere there. If there's no JS errors in the console then it's to do with your selector, but if there are errors then that should point you in the right direction.

Comment: selector is clearly fine, it's just a classname and it matches the html

Comment: @Marcus the escape() is a function that is called from an init.php file at the top of the page. i use it alot so i know its not that. I have also checked the isset($_POST[]) but that is working all fine. and no the console dose not return anything so i don't think anything is actually being called but cant work it out.

Comment: @LouisShiggyLombardi - As stated, youre not going to get any ajax becuse your event handler function isn't even firing.. focus on that before you worry about your ajax.. again.. are you including jQuery? where?

Comment: @PootieTang Hi, yeah i have included my jquery in a header.php file. I have some other functions including add comments / delete comments that are working

Comment: the name of the file you included it in is irrelevant, what's relevant is the location of your <script>s relative to the location of your jQuery include. what have you done to ensire that jQuery is loaded and working? run this in the console to make sure `alert(jQuery('a').length);` if it alerts the number of links on your page then you know jQuery is loadde properly and working.

Comment: @PootieTang I am getting a number of links called back which means it is loaded in ok.

Comment: well that's bad news, because it means the issue is somewhere else. you'll have to post full code or a link ot the live website.

Comment: @PootieTang You were right! Im not sure what it was but i changed a couple of divs and  I have managed to get it working now(almost), but i am having a few other problems! I'll post an update very soon

Answer (score 1):

FIXED IT!

```
<div id="comments_post" class="comments-block">
    <div class="comments_display">
        <?php 
            $get_comments = db::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM video_comments WHERE video_id = ? ORDER BY added DESC LIMIT 0, {$resultsPerPage}", array($vid_id)); 
            if(!$get_comments->results()){ ?>
                <div class="comment-header">
                </div>
                <div class="comment-body">
                    <p class="text-center">No Comments....</p>
                </div>
        <?php

            } else {
                foreach ($get_comments->results() as $comment) { ?>
                <div class="comment-header">
                    <?php echo $comment->username . ' | ' . $comment->added;  

                    if ($user->data()->user_id == $comment->user_id OR $user->hasPermission('admin')) { ?>
                            <i id="<?php echo $comment->id; ?>"class="fa  fa-trash-o onl-link-icon text-right del-com" title="delete comment?"></i>
                        <?php
                    } ?>


                </div>
                <div class="comment-body">
                    <p><?php echo $comment->comment; ?></p>
                </div>
            <?php
                    $x++; 
                }

                if($x == $resultsPerPage) {
                ?>
                <div class="loadbutton"><button class="loadmore" data-page="2">Load More</button></div>

                <?php 
                } else {
                    echo 'no more comments';
                } 
            }
        ?>
</div>
</div>


$( document ).on( 'click', '.loadmore', function () {
       $(this).text('Loading...');
       var btn = $(this).parent();
        $.ajax({
          url: 'load.php',
          type: 'POST',
          cache: false,
          data: {
            page:$(this).data('page'),
          },
          success: function(response){
            if(response){
              btn.hide();
              $(".comments-block").append(response);
            }
          }
        });
  });
```